# Combinational interpretation of $\binom n 3 = \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n-1} (i-1)(n-i) $

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

What is the interpretation of this identity? 
I've tried picking elements one-by-one and grouping them, looking for geometric interpretations by drawing polygons and still no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}3$ ways to choose $3$ numbers from the set $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Now count these $3$-element sets in groups organized by the *middle* number in the set. If $i$ is the middle number, it can be anywhere from $2$ through $n-1$. There are $i-1$ ways to pick a smaller number from $[n]$ and $n-i$ ways to pick a bigger number from $[n]$ so there are $(i-1)(n-i)$ $3$-element subsets of $[n]$ having $i$ as middle number.